# "Started the washing machine" vs "started the washing machine up."

Tags: word-usage

What's the correct construction? Example sentences:

> I didn't start the watching machine (up).
>
> The washing machine is spinning. Who started it (up)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about devices or machines, as far as I know, both *start* and *start up* can be used interchangeably:

> Go and **start** the car, I'll be there in a moment.
>   Go and **start up** the car, I'll be there in a moment.
>
> My pad won't **start**.  Can you fix it?
>   My pad won't **start up**.  Can you fix it?

There may be idiomatic exceptions, but I can't think of any.  However because "start up" means "get running", you don't normally use "start up" with things like events.

> The race is scheduled to **start** at ten.

Unless you mean to imply that you want to *get things going*

> Welcome to the tenth national gathering of the English Learners' Society!  Let's get things **started up** by singing our theme song!